# Player streaming audio over http/rtsp (shoutcast also) BlackBerry app

Tags: blackberry, audio-streaming, blackberry-simulator

how can i develop a simple audio or audio/video player for blackberry over http and rtsp protocol for BB ?

I'll try to use:

```
Player p = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer("rtsp://...");
p.realize();
VolumeControl volume = (VolumeControl)p.getControl("VolumeControl");
volume.setLevel(30);
p.prefetch();
p.start();
```

it doesn't work on simulator using Eclipse plugin.

EDIT: I need to play Flash radio and shoutcast especially.

Comment: we need some more details that rtsp and http is working fine but you have to specify what is your target devise abd OS?. Also we want to know some sample url which is not working in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the "Streaming media - Start to finish" application from RIM here:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Streaming-media-Start-to-finish/ta-p/488255

A lot of the complexity in implementing a streaming media application on a mobile device is handling the different transport protocols: Wi-Fi, 3G, EDGE etc. Whilst getting started I would stick to using Wi-Fi only. To do this on the simulator do the following:

1. Go to Wireless Connections and connect to the 'Default WLAN connection', this will use your normal PC network connection for Internet connectivity.
2. Append ";interface=wifi" to your streaming URLs.

You can always build in a transport handler later once the app is working over Wi-Fi.

Comment: Have you guys have tested the streaming using BIS plan? On wifi it works but we are unable to stream it using data plan(BIS plan) .Can anybody provide us the assistance for the same.